# Merge multiple workbooks with multiple worksheets into a master workbook using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

- I need a copysheets method that will merge multiple workbooks that contain multiple worksheets.
- Each tab/sheet name in the workbook identical to the sheetnames of the the other workbooks I would like to merge together.
- I would like to merge the contents of (workbook1,sheet1), (workbook2, sheet1), (workbook3, sheet1) into sheet1 of the new master workbook, then (workbook1, sheet2) , (workbook2, sheet2), workbook3, sheet2) into sheet2 of the new master workbook. and so on into a new master workbook.
- I would like the data to be inserted one below the other, like first 10 rows from sheet1, then the next from 10  from sheet2 and so on.

The output would copy the only the first sheet contents appended over and over. I'm receiving the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet named 'Sheet1'
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.validateSheetName(XSSFWorkbook.java:890)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.createSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:843)
at MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.mergeExcelFiles(MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.java:121)
at MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.main(MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.java:316)
```

Here is my code:

```
    public class MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet{
      public static void mergeExcelFiles(File file) throws IOException {
          XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
          System.out.println(file.getName());
    String directoryName = "C:Documents\\File.xlsx";
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file1 : fList){
        if (file1.isFile()){
         String ParticularFile = file1.getName();
         FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(directoryName+"\\"+ParticularFile));
        XSSFWorkbook b = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) { 
        for(int worksheetIndex = 0; worksheetIndex<b.getNumberOfSheets(); worksheetIndex++)
        {
        XSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet(b.getSheetName(worksheetIndex));
        String worksheetName = b.getSheetName(worksheetIndex);
        System.out.println("test " + worksheetName);
        copySheets(book.createSheet(), b.getSheetAt(i));
        System.out.println("Copying..");
      }
          }
    }
    try {

     writeFile(book, file);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }

        protected static void writeFile(XSSFWorkbook book, File file) throws Exception {



    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    book.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println(file+ " is written successfully..");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


  private static void copySheets(XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet){     

      copySheets( newSheet, sheet, true);
  }     

//  private static void copySheets(XSSFWorkbook newWorkbook, XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet, boolean copyStyle){ 
  private static void copySheets( XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet, boolean copyStyle){     
    int newRownumber = newSheet.getLastRowNum();
    int maxColumnNum = 0;     
    Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap<Integer, XSSFCellStyle>() : null;    

    for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {     
      XSSFRow srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);     
      XSSFRow destRow = newSheet.createRow(i + newRownumber);     
      if (srcRow != null) {     
        //copyRow(newWorkbook, sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);  
          copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap); 
        if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {     
            maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();     
        }     
      }     
    }     
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {     
      newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));     
    }     
  }     


  public static void copyRow( XSSFSheet srcSheet, XSSFSheet destSheet, XSSFRow srcRow, XSSFRow destRow, Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap) { 
  destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());
    Set<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions = new TreeSet<CellRangeAddress>();
  //  for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) { 


    int deltaRows = destRow.getRowNum()-srcRow.getRowNum();


int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); 
    if(j<0){j=0;} 
    for (; j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) { 

      XSSFCell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j);
      XSSFCell newCell = destRow.getCell(j);
      if (oldCell != null) {     
        if (newCell == null) {     
          newCell = destRow.createCell(j);     
        }     

        copyCell( oldCell, newCell, styleMap);CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = getMergedRegion( srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(), (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());
        if (mergedRegion != null) {

            CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(mergedRegion.getFirstRow()+deltaRows, mergedRegion.getLastRow()+deltaRows, mergedRegion.getFirstColumn(),  mergedRegion.getLastColumn());
            //System.out.println("New merged region: " + newMergedRegion.toString());

            if (isNewMergedRegion( newMergedRegion, mergedRegions)) {
                mergedRegions.add(newMergedRegion);
                destSheet.addMergedRegion(newMergedRegion);
            }
        }


      }     
    }                
  }


  public static void copyCell( XSSFCell oldCell, XSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap) { 
  if(styleMap != null) {     
      int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();     
      XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);     
      if(newCellStyle == null){     
        //newCellStyle = newWorkbook.createCellStyle(); 
          newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());     
        styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);     
      }     
      newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);   
    }     
    switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {     
      case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:     
        newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue());     
        break;     
      case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:     
        newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());     
        break;     
      case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:     
        newCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);     
        break;     
      case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:     
        newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());     
        break;     
      case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:     
        newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());     
        break;     
      case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:     
        newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());     
        break;     
      default:     
        break;     
    }
  }


         public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion( XSSFSheet sheet, int rowNum, short cellNum) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
          CellRangeAddress merged = (CellRangeAddress) sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
               if (merged.isInRange(rowNum, cellNum)) {
              return merged;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }




  private static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion, Collection<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions) {
      return !mergedRegions.contains(newMergedRegion);
  } 


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        mergeExcelFiles(new File("C:\\Documents\\test.xlsx"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The first part of your "Question" is a nice description of a whole programming project which is much too broad for a question here. The last paragraph describes problems using some code we don't know. Sorry, but as it is now, this question is not answerable. Please ask **one** concrete question about **one** concrete problem and show the code which has that problem.

Comment: I've updated my code for your review, or should I start over with a specific question?

Comment: At least for me, fixing your whole code is too broad to be in an answer block here. So I will not do that. So, as told already, please ask **one** concrete question about **one** concrete problem and show the code which has **that** problem. Btw. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet named 'Sheet1'` means exactly what it says. A `Excel` workbook cannot have two sheets having the same name "Sheet1". And the stack trace will tell you what code line throws that exception.

Comment: I added the Stack Trace                  :                                
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet named 'Sheet1'
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.validateSheetName(XSSFWorkbook.java:890)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.createSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:843)
 at MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.mergeExcelFiles(MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.java:121)
 at MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.main(MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.java:316)

Comment: What code line is `MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet.java:121`? I suspect it is `XSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet(b.getSheetName(worksheetIndex));` and `b.getSheetName(worksheetIndex)` returns `Sheet1` and `book` already contains a sheet having that name. But the whole logic behind your nested for loops having iterator `i` and `worksheetIndex` is not clear to me. It seems illogically. At least because you are calling `copySheets(book.createSheet(), b.getSheetAt(i));` using a new sheet in `book` again.

Comment: That's where I seem to get confuse too.  What would I need to do so that the  contents of (workbook1,sheet1), (workbook2, sheet1), (workbook3, sheet1) into sheet1 of the new master workbook, then (workbook1, sheet2) , (workbook2, sheet2), workbook3, sheet2) into sheet2 of the new master workbook. and so on into a new master workbook.

Comment: As said, much too broad for a question here. Wild guess `for (int i = 0; i < b.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) { XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheet(b.getSheetName(i)); if (sheet == null) sheet = book.createSheet(b.getSheetName(i)); copySheets(sheet, b.getSheetAt(i)); }`? That would at least avoid the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Axel, you ROCK! Your wild guess worked!! It's exactly what I needed and it worked!! Thank you so much!

Comment: How would I iterate through the pages without copying the first row (the headings)?